# Unable to shutdown, only reboot

Tags: 11.04, shutdown, reboot

Ever since I upgraded to 11.04, I have been unable to **shutdown** my computer.

I tried using :

`shutdown now`, `poweroff`, and `halt`. But they don't work! The only one that does is `reboot`.

Here is the output of running `lspci` in terminal.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] (rev a1)
02:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
02:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 03)
04:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 03)
05:03.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7130 Video Broadcast Decoder (rev 01)
05:04.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6102 [Rhine-II] (rev 43)
05:05.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

Does anyone know what happened? Thank you!

Comment: What does actually happen when you try `sudo shutdown -P now`?

Comment: Have a look at the log files (system settings->system->log file viewer) and see if there is any errors during shutdown (syslog) or check `dmesg| more` or `dmesg|tail 100` (last 100 records). If there are any error please add them to your question.

Answer (score 2):

you could try:

```
sudo init 0
```

hth, marc

Comment: thank u for replying,it could run ,but it stopped,when it printed system halted  .that means init 0 does not work! so I am thinking about maybe it is my showcard driver error,because before i installed my show card drvier ,it was ok .

Answer (score 0):

```
man shutdown
```

May help

Or try

```
shutdown --help
```

This will give you all the parameters for shutting down. I think an extra letter needs to be added to ensure the power is turned off after the operating system closes.

Comment: =_=! sorry, I know how to use command shutdown

Comment: @Hongyu Ye - On older systems, shutting down the computer didn't actually power it off (I remember having a system that had a switch not unlike the ones you find on power supplies), so telling an OS to shutdown doesn't necessarily power off the machine.